# How to write setup.py that installs package except for one submodule?

Tags: python, distutils

I'm working on porting a library to python 3, however, one of its submodules is terribly broken, all the unit tests fail on Python 3 because of that, and the author has advised me to delete it rather than wait for him to fix it. If I do that, however, merging will surely be more difficult. Is there any way to just tell distutils to not install it (or its test case)?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Specifying the files to distribute](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) and [Manifest-related options](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-related-options).

Comment: Specifically Manifest.in's prune command, actually. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. Manifest.in only handles sdists, not actual builds/installs. How do I control what's built/installed?